# What does AddTablesWithEntityFramework() vs AddTables(new MobileAppTableConfiguration()?

Tags: c#, zumo

I have been using

```
.AddTables(new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
    .MapTableControllers()
    .AddEntityFramework())
```

to setup my MobileAppConfiguration, but recently saw in Adrian Hall's book https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/

```
.AddTablesWithEntityFramework()
```

How are these different? Should I be using the latter?

This call comes in Startup.cs in a standard Azure Mobile App, e.g.,

```
    public static void SetupMobileApp(IAppBuilder app, IKernel kernel)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        //new MobileAppConfiguration()
        //    .UseDefaultConfiguration()
        //    .ApplyTo(config);

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .MapApiControllers()
            .AddTables(new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                .MapTableControllers()
                .AddEntityFramework())                
            .AddPushNotifications()
            .MapLegacyCrossDomainController()
            .ApplyTo(config);
```

Comment: Nobody can guess the type of the object that these methods exist on. A bit of context might make this question answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, it only sets the default settings for **EntityFramework** with **TableController**. [Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Entity/Extensions/EntityMobileAppConfigurationExtensions.cs#L46).